# unequal intervals highchart gauges

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am using Angular Gauge from HighChart and wanted to know if it is possible to have unequal intervals. Currently, unequal intervals on the Y-axis effects the size of each plot band in the gauge.How can I have equal plot band sizes with unequal intervals on Y-axis.

Here is an example of the intervals-0-86, 86-88, 88-90, 90-96 and 96-100.

I have tried so far-

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'gauge',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBackgroundImage: null,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      plotShadow: false
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Percentage %'
    },

    pane: {
      center: ['50%', '85%'],
      size: '130%',
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      background: {
        backgroundColor: '#EEE',
        innerRadius: '80%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
      }
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    // the value axis
    yAxis: [{
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      minorTickInterval: 'auto',
      minorTickWidth: 0,
      minorTickLength: 10,
      minorTickPosition: 'outside',
      minorTickColor: '#666',
      tickPixelInterval: 50,
      tickInterval: 6,
      tickWidth: 2,
      tickPosition: 'outside',
      tickLength: 10,
      tickColor: '#666',
      labels: {
        step: 1,
        distance: 20,
        rotation: 'auto',
        style: {
          fontSize: '15px'
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      plotBands: [{
        from: 0,
        to: 86,
        color: '#bf0000',
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%'
      }, {
        from: 86,
        to: 88,
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        color: '#fcfe00'
      }, {
        from: 88,
        to: 90,
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        color: '#00ae50'
      }, {
        from: 90,
        to: 96,
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        color: '#2f74b4'
      }, {
        from: 96,
        to: 100,
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        color: '#7131a0'
      }]
    }],
    plotOptions: {
      gauge: {
        dial: {
          backgroundColor: "silver",
          baseLength: "80%",
          baseWidth: 4,
          borderColor: "grey",
          borderWidth: 1,
          radius: "90%",
          rearLength: "0",
          topWidth: 1
        },
        pivot: {
          backgroundColor: "silver",
          borderColor: "grey",
          borderWidth: 1,
          radius: 5
        },
        dataLabels: {
          y: 3,
          style: {
            fontSize: "15px"
          },
          borderWidth: 0,
          useHTML: false
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Speed',
      data: [90],
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ''
      }
    }]

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure what you would like to achieve, could you give more specific information about your issue and live example of this issue? Like jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, As per your requiremnt It seems like you want to achieve similar to this..

[image]

where min and max should updated accordingly.

**Solution-**

As I am understanding you want to set all value in **red** below 86%. correct? so why don't you change the min value of the chart. I mean while passing value  to  chart manipulate your input data accordingly and pass corresponding label to it.

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Answer (score 0):

Well, High Chart doesn't provide direct method to show selected labels on the axis.

So there is alternative way to achieve this.
Below is the running code for this-

JSFiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/Lxoc4d8r/16/

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'gauge',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBackgroundImage: null,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      plotShadow: false
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'This is custom High Chart'
    },

    pane: {
      center: ['50%', '85%'],
      size: '130%',
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      background: {
        backgroundColor: '#EEE',
        innerRadius: '80%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
      }
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    // the value axis
    yAxis: [{
      min: 80,
      max: 100,
      minorTickInterval: 'auto',
      minorTickWidth: 0,
      minorTickLength: 10,
      minorTickPosition: 'outside',
      minorTickColor: '#666',
      tickPixelInterval: 20,
      //tickInterval: 1,
      tickWidth: 0,
      tickPosition: 'outside',
      tickLength: 10,
      tickColor: '#666',
      labels: {
        step: 1,
        distance: 20,
        rotation: 'auto',
        style: {
          fontSize: '14px'
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      plotBands: [{
        from: 80,
        to: 86,
        color: '#bf0000',
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%'
      }, {
        from: 86,
        to: 88,
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        color: '#fcfe00'
      }, {
        from: 88,
        to: 90,
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        color: '#00ae50'
      }, {
        from: 90,
        to: 96,
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        color: '#2f74b4'
      }, {
        from: 96,
        to: 100,
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        color: '#7131a0'
      }]
    }],
    plotOptions: {
      gauge: {
        dial: {
          backgroundColor: "silver",
          baseLength: "80%",
          baseWidth: 4,
          borderColor: "grey",
          borderWidth: 1,
          radius: "90%",
          rearLength: "0",
          topWidth: 1
        },
        pivot: {
          backgroundColor: "silver",
          borderColor: "grey",
          borderWidth: 1,
          radius: 5
        },
        dataLabels: {
          y: 3,
          style: {
            fontSize: "15px"
          },
          borderWidth: 0,
          useHTML: false
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Speed',
      data: [90],
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ''
      }
    }]

  });
  
  try{
  var DisplayLabels = [86, 88, 90, 96];
 var labels = $(".highcharts-yaxis-labels > text>tspan");
 labels.each(function(i, node){
   if( DisplayLabels.indexOf(parseInt($(node).text())) == -1){
   $(node).hide();
   } else{
    $(node).text($(node).text() + "%");
   }
 });
  } catch(err){
  console.dir(err);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but my min range is 0 and max range is 100. need to divide unequally.